# How to split url in sql server like this

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the url

```
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i
```

I want result like this

```
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e
www.abc.com/a/b/c/d
www.abc.com/a/b/c
www.abc.com/a/b
www.abc.com/a
www.abc.com/
```

Please look out this code..

```
            declare @length as int
            declare @Totallength as int
            declare @min as int
            declare @strURL as varchar(max)
            set @strURL='www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i'
            set @min=1
            set @length=(SELECT LEN(@strURL) - LEN(REPLACE(@strURL, '/', '')))
            set @Totallength=(select len(@strURL))
            if(@length>1)
            begin
            while(@min<=@length)
            begin
            --select @strURL=left(@strURL,charindex('/',@strURL)-1)
            SELECT  @strURL = SUBSTRING( @strURL, CHARINDEX('/', @strURL) + 1, @Totallength)
            print @strURL
            set @min=@min+1
            -- print @min
            end
            end
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want an arbitrary number of strings to be returned from one URL, depending on the number of / (slashes) in that URL?

Comment: Hi Vérace, Expected result was mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got alternate solution for the same.

```
declare @S nvarchar(100) = 'www.abc.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i'

while PATINDEX('%[/]%' , @S) > 0 BEGIN
    SET @S = LEFT (@S,LEN(@S) - PATINDEX('%[/]%' , REVERSE(@S)))
SELECT @S
END
```

Comment: If you have a lot to split, that's going to be slow and resource intensive.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one which is heavily based on Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8k:

```
declare @url VARCHAR(8000), @delimiter char(1)

set @url = 'www.abc.com/aaa/bb/c/ddd/ee/ff/g/h/iii'
set @delimiter = '/'

;WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@url),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
ctePos(N1) AS (
                 SELECT t.N-1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@url,t.N,1) = @delimiter
                 union all 
                 select datalength(@url)
                )
select left(@url, N1) + case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N1) = 1 then '/' else '' end as URL
from ctePos order by N1 desc
```

This should outperform any loop / recursive code if used as a function.

DelimitedSplit8k source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/